# Wildcards in SHOW GRANTS FOR <user>@<hostname> IN MYSQL 8.0

Tags: mysql

Can I use wildcards to see the grants of all users in MySQL 8.0 ?

`SHOW GRANTS FOR '%'@'%';` doesn't work.
I 've had exported all the SHOW GRANT statements for all users into a text like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE mysql.user.user NOT IN ('mysql.infoschema','mysql.session','mysql.sys') INTO outfile '/var/lib/mysql-files/show_grants.txt';
```

but I don't know how to use it in order to create a table with 2 columns (1 for the user and 1 for the grants).

Comment: No; this is why [pt-show-grants](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-show-grants.html) was developed.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you for the response, I will check it out!